# Does Xcode 3.2.3 supports core Utillity functions?

Tags: frameworks, xcode3.2, utility

I am using **Xcode 3.2.3** When i am insist to use utility function for my app . I couldn't find the **CGpointUtills** function in my Core Graphics Framework folder. Like this

```
developer/platforms/IphoneSimulatorOs/Developer/SDK/Simulator4.0/System/Library/Framework/CoreGraphic/
```

Is it means Xcode 3.2.3 wont support Utility function or any other issues related with this?

thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CGPointUtils is ***not*** a part of Core Graphics or the iPhone SDK.  It actually comes from a book, ["Beginning IOS 5 Development: Exploring the IOS SDK"](http://books.google.com/books?id=sikKz-oQNFIC&pg=PA628&lpg=PA628) by Jeff LaMarche and a couple other authors.

You can get a copy of the CGPointUtils code by doing some Googling.  I can see it here in the # 1 hit for "CGPointUtils.h":  http://code.google.com/p/hedgewars/source/browse/project_files/HedgewarsMobile/Classes

Grab it from there and then drop the .c and the .h file into your project and you should be all set.

Comment: Thanx man. But how can i copy the link into my project. i cant grab and drop into mine

Comment: Just download the .c and .h files and then import them into your project.